# Does firebase store user's name and email when using FCM for push messages?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to understand how much data is stored on Firebase when we use FCM to send a push notification. I know we need to have a registered unique device ID on firebase to ensure that device gets a notification. I want to know in specific if a user's name and email also get stored on it. Is it also possible to register a new user without an email on firebase?

I've gone over the firebase documentation provided [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/users#the_user_lifecycle) but I'm unclear about the user name and email getting shared with each instance invocation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Firebase Cloud Messaging** has no concept of a user, it merely sends a message to the device on which the specific token was minted.

It only stores the minimum information that it needs to deliver the messages, which (given that it doesn't have any concept of a user) does **not** incude a user name or their email address.

---

The link you provide is to the documentation of **Firebase Authentication**, which is a completely separate product within the Firebase platform that *does* store user information. But you don't need to use Firebase Authentication in order to use its Cloud Messaging.

Comment: Thanks so much for the clarification! I assumed firebase auth is necessary for a Cloud Messaging to happen successfully. So as long as I have my app running on a registered device I can send them push notifications. And the only thing that FCM stores is the device ID and nothing else concerned to the user

Comment: Yup, that's correct.